# YUI3 calling a function

Tags: javascript, yui, yui3

```
top.on('click', function(){
    anim.run();
});
```

I have an anim function, and was wondering why I can't call it like this

```
top.on('click', anim.run);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
top.on('click', function () { anim.run(); });
```

or

```
top.on('click', Y.bind(anim.run, anim));
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `this` is not `anim` in the second case as you're retrieving the `run` function and not calling it from `anim`.

For example:

```
var a = {
  b: function () {
    return this.c;
  },
  c: 1
},
c = 2;

a.b() === 1;
var bMethod = a.b;
bMethod() === 2;
```

Comment: No, unless `run` doesn't reference `this`.